# Filter multiple attributes

Tags: jquery, search, filter, attributes

I have a small filter script, that shows images baed on the alt tags. But I also have divs that can be searched. For correct validation I cannot give them an alt tag, I have to use aria-label.

So: How can I search for both alt tag and aria-label?

```
//Search
$("#search").on("keyup", function () {

  if ($(this).val().length >= 3) {
    // hide everything,
    $(".brand").hide();
    $(".brandsslider").hide();
    // get the text in the input
    var mySelector = $(this).val();
    // show any alt that contains the input
    var myImgs = $("[alt*='" + mySelector + "' i]");
    myImgs.show();
  } else {
    $(".brand").hide();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just combine your selector to target both attributes.

```
var myImgs = $("[alt*='"+mySelector+"', [aria-label*='"+mySelector+"']");
```

(Note, I removed the stray `i` from your original selector as I can't see what use that would be, and would cause your attribute selector to fail.)